# Aggregate operation in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a problem statement where I have data of a vehicle in a Es, having fields time in secs, time in milliseconds and velocity. Now I want to fetch the data and plot speed vs time graph in frontend. But the problem is there are lot of data points as for one sec there are 30-40 milliseconds entries and corresponding speed as well. Now to reduce the datapoints I want to get the average of velocities for one second so that I will have only one datapoint for one sec. How can I achieve that in  Es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your mapping looks like -

```
{
  "properties": {
    "ms": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "seconds": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "velocity": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": "256"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The below nested aggregation will work -
You will get your datapoints in field "averageMsInSecond".

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "seconds_buckets": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "seconds"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "averageMsInSecond": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "ms"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In order to get average value for a second, you need to read key in seconds_buckets aggs and use it along with averageMsInSecond.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The OP is looking for avg velocity. Having `velocity` field of type `text`/`keyword` won't work

Comment: Since, the question did not specify the mapping, I assumed the one. However, you can alter the answer as per your needs of aggregation. The intent here is to use sub aggregations properly.

Comment: I am looking for a query like select average(speed), sec from index group by sec